# hide protected system files in windows 10

Tags: windows

Help, I accidentaly used cmd on windows 10 with this command 
"attrib -s -h *.* /s /" on C:\ to check if I hada  virus. now I get volume has no label warnings in cmd and all my system protected files can't be hidden with options anymore. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd try [`sfc /scannow`](https://ss64.com/nt/sfc.html) (no guarantee of success).

Answer (score 0):

Did this command even execute successfully?

This command contains 2 error. 
  1. You need to remove . (dot) after -h
  2. You need to remove the last / (forward slash)

The correct command would be attrib -h -s /s

And even is this command got executed, it will give access denied because even administrators does not have permission to change attributes of system files.